# RabbitMQ with re-connection

Tags: node.js, sockets, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

I'm starting to code `RabbitMQ` queues with `Node.js` running with `GeddyJs`.

One of my first question was: "What if things goes wrong with the socket?", and I didn't found any error-proof solution for that... Only starting up, but no reconnections or anything else.

My code is following the example: https://github.com/squaremo/rabbit.js/blob/master/example/socketio/server.js

Is it something I should be considering? And if so, how to (securely) implement it with `rabbit.js` or `amqplib`?

Answer (score 0):

[Socket.io](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client) handles reconnection automatically. See the readme carefully ;)

Comment: bit will Rabbit.js reconnect and also provide the binds for all exchange and triggers necessary?